# Why can we declare a variable of a nested class before defining the class

Tags: java, inner-classes

For example,

```
public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item>
{
 private Node first; // top of stack (most recently added node)
 private int N;      // number of items
 private class Node
 {  // nested class to define nodes
  Item item;
  Node next; 
 }
```

Why can we declare first to be of type Node before defining what Node is. Also, as an extension, why are instance variables always declared first. What happens if we define some instance variables, then some methods, then more instance variables, and more methods.

Comment: Other than initialization order, the order of declarations does not matter.

Comment: Its a convention to declare variables then declare constructors and after you declare methods

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no attempt at resolution until the entire class has been parsed. For the same reason, you can call class methods that haven't been defined yet.

Instance variable are not always declared first. You can declare things in any order you like, subject only to initialization order constraints.